# VSCode JSON Object Color Syntax

Tags: sublimetext3, visual-studio-code

I am using the **Mac Classic** in [Sublime](https://github.com/SublimeText/LegacyColorSchemes/blob/master/Mac%20Classic.tmTheme) & [VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkjoep.mac-classic-theme) and I am trying to get JSON object colors to match. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

### Sublime:

[image]

### VS Code

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed the [Javascript Babel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel) editor and it ended up working.